# Matrix multiplication in Python (defining the input)

Tags: python

```
print("Hi sir!")
X=list(input("please enter the first matrix X="))
Y=list(input("Please enter the second matrix Y="))
result=list(input("please enter the template of the result matrix in the form of zeros (0)="))
# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

With this code, I get an error that says "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'".

in this I need the user himself to put the matrices he want however when I put the same matrices in the code editor it works so I think the errors comes from the way of defining the input...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to convert the input to a numeric type.  Python input comes in string form.  Rather than

```
X=list(input("please enter the first matrix X="))
```

you'll need to extract the individual elements to something numeric.  That said ... shame on you for not bothering to print the values causing the problem.  You wrote a triple-nested loop without checking the values you sent into it.  A simple

print X

Would show the basic problem.  This is a low-tech, but powerful debugging tool: if you have a sick patient, ask where it hurts; prod a few places.  Then you won't have to come to the emergency room (StackOverflow).  :-)

That said, let's get back to the input processing.  I expect that you'll want to take the matrix, one line at a time, grab the individual numbers, and convert them to floats.  Something like this ...

```
in_line = input("please enter the first matrix X=")
value_list = in_line.split()
X = [float(x) for x in value_list]
```

You can reduce this to a single line, but this helps show you the stages.  Repeat this for each line in the matrix, and then make a list of those lists.  Do likewise for Y.

Does that get you unstuck?

Comment: I didn't get your last point could you please give me an example ?

Comment: Not quite, for two reasons:  (1) StackOverflow is for specific coding problems, not a tutorial service.  I sense that you have a conceptual problem with the data structures you're trying to handle; (2) I don't know what you imagine for input and your resulting data structure.  You *really* need to finish your posting per [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We've explain the problem you posted; you should now work with what we've given you.  If you have another problem, please post another question.  Otherwise, we get into a long tutorial session.